# Very old cartoon of a mermaid or sea maiden probably from Warner bros animation

Tags: story-identification, animation, mermaids

I'm looking for a very old cartoon animation that was probably done by Warner Bros animation. My father got this vhs tape when I was like 2 or 4 years old and I watched the tape several times over the years (1994-2000). The tape was one of those homemade recorded or something like that because it was like 6-8 hours long. It had so many Looney Tunes cartoons and the short animated stories.

The story I'm looking for is about a mermaid or a sea maiden (a female that came out of the sea): she falls in love with a man, I believe in the end either they both die or she dies (I think I recall someone killing her with an arrow).
I recall that she had to go back to the ocean but she didn't wanto return back, and they shoot the arrow at her. I think she dies in the man's hands or something like that.

The animation was like 5-10 minutes long.  I don't recall if it was just narration of the story or actual dialogue between the characters, or both. I say old because it had that 40s Warner Bros animation look or newer.
I really want to say the female had blonde hair, white, she might have a white or semi-transparent dress when she comes out of the sea. I don't recall much of the rest of the story, I think it was a forbidden love story with a sad ending.

I have tried looking for it but I just get Disney' Little Mermaid  or the adaptations of the original book.  And the tape got stuck in the vhs player, and it ripped.

Comment: One of these, perhaps? https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title=The+Little+Mermaid&genres=animation

Comment: None,  I even looked for just the word mermaid. I don't recall if she was a mermaid or a sea princess or something like that

Comment: Does this ring any bells?
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCgqdVN4vB8
Legend of Sirius (1981)

Comment: Not it.  But thanks

Comment: This looks like the ending you're talking about, but I am certain it is not it:https://youtu.be/_b5Arzjjytw?t=3m41s

Comment: Little mermaid, 1975 movie? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWGu7dMzm6I

Comment: Is noneof them. The story is 5-10 minutes long.

Comment: Probably not https://youtu.be/pCYkE5ouI88 although it is shorter.

Comment: not it.  If anyone has seen the old looney tunes or merrie melodies,  they were about 5-8 minutes long.  It looked similar to that animation and laated that long.  It was a tale told in few minutes.

Comment: This sounds pretty dark for a Warner Bros cartoon, and I can’t see it being a Looney Tunes or Merry Melodies short. WB had a few other animated shorts but I don’t think this was theirs. There were other studios that did short cartoons then, and many of them used similar styles (animators got around those days).